# pre_get_comments or the_content filter

Tags: theme-development, hooks, the-content

What is the best practice to show **social icons** always on all the posts and pages.

Already I am firing `pre_get_comments` in my `functions.php` to show a sidebar between the post content and the comments. Also I added the code after `the_content()` of `page.php`...

The Question: How can I choose the propper Hook?

1. Fire `pre_get_comments` + add code after `the_content()` in `page.php`...
2. Filter `the_content()` and use conditionals, something as `is_singular()...`

What is the best practice? Why?

Comment: If it helps, there are several cases in which `pre_get_comments` won't get fired: post types without comments support, specific templates not loading the comments' template, posts without comments if the comments are closed, etcetera. I would probably stick with `the_content` filter facing several conditionals first.

Comment: If you want to add social icons to post and pages, why use a hook for comments? Use `the_content` filter.

Comment: Good Point. Yes you both are right, comments are not always firing with content. I choice the_content filter adding some conditional before inside the custom_function. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @cybmeta the most convenient way to add something on every post would be to use [`the_content` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

This may give you unexpected results on archive pages, because some themes use `the_content` to display information on those, while others use `the_excerpt`. So, depending on what you want, you may want to use the filter on `the_content` only on [singular pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) or add the same [filter to `the excerpt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt) as well.`